# oauth 2.0 to microsoft auth server

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest

Need help with formatting a token request.  I've googled around and looked at numerous docs.  Fiddler response is yelling about "grant_type" but it's included.

```
POST http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=https%3A//login.microsoftonline.com/[removed]/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4400
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 104
Authorization: Basic YWZyaWVkOnRlc3Q=
Origin: http://localhost:4400
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
X-Ripple-User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.2; en-us; Nexus S Build/GRH78C) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4400/login.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

grant_type='password'&username='afried'&password='test'&client_id='[removed]'
```

I have also tried sending them in without the ' (grant_type=password, eg), as well as creating an object (I have tried stringifying it):

```
var data = {    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': userID,
    'password': password,
    'client_id': clientId
};
```

which posts to fiddler as

```
[object Object]
```

The Authorization header is username : password, I am under the impression that with a password grant, you can request directly from the token endpoint without hitting the auth endpoint first, since you're sending the username/password.

I have .withCredentials = true.  Content security policy is also ok.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I know it's something simple, I just can't see it, and I guess I just don't have the experience, nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: It looks like I had to set a content type header.  I'm past the grant_type issue but now it's wanting a "resource"... Still working on that, but I think the answer is simply "Add a Content-Type header[I used application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it appears to be working"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that winds up here.  This is a specific answer, but if you have similar trouble with username/password grants (grant_type=password), this is what worked for me:

1 - you can get the token directly from /oauth2/token.  No need to authorize first.  Since you are sending username/password, it doesn't need the preemptive step.

2- Request headers
 - Authorization - Basic + base64encode username:password
 - Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded - even for mobile apps, json won't work, bad request.

3- withCredentials = true (I did not test without, but I'm pretty sure this is mandatory for mobile always - correct me if I'm wrong).

4 - exact format I used for POST data:

```
var data =
    "resource=http://[serviceName].azurewebsites.net" +
    "&grant_type=password" +
    "&username=" + userID + "@[xxx].onmicrosoft.com" + //so they don't have to type it.  This is sufficient for my company and app.
    "&password=" + password +
    "&client_id=" + clientId +
    "&response_type=token";
var dataFinal = encodeURI(data); //in case.  Didn't test without.

request.send(dataFinal);
```

It actually seemed to matter the order I sent them in.  When I sent resource last, I kept getting a message "Cannot find application named [servicename].azurewebsites.n" (it was trimming the last 2 characters).  It seems to be very buggy.  That may have just been a problem with how microsoft sends the response, but it looks wrong, so I'm mentioning it.